# ics not showing up in my iPad's iCal

Tags: php, ipad, icalendar

I have a php page that I'm using to test sample ics data for the iPad, but when I tap the **Open in "Calendar"** button in Safari, it triggers the Calendar app, but it opens without showing me anything about the events.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

$ical = "
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. "160000Z
DTEND:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. "170000Z
SUMMARY:Paul's Birthday
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:" . gmdate('Ym').'T'. "230000Z
DTEND:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. "240000Z
SUMMARY:John's Birthday
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR";


//echo out
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
echo $ical;

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is a sample file that gets generated from the php:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20121017T204856Z
DTSTART:20121017T160000Z
DTEND:20121017T170000Z
SUMMARY:Paul's Birthday
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20121017T204856Z
DTSTART:201210T230000Z
DTEND:20121017T240000Z
SUMMARY:John's Birthday
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: how does the resulting file look like?

Comment: I updated with sample output, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself.  Apparently iCal doesn't like having a newline before **BEGIN:VCALENDAR**. I expected iCal to strip out that kind of stuff but apparently they don't, so if anybody else has issues with iCal be sure to check that the string doesn't start with a newline!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. On your second VEVENT the day on the DTSTART is missing.

Replace

> gmdate('Ym')

with

> gmdate('Ymd')

Comment: Did you try testing this on your iPad? I removed the typo but it the event still doesn't show :/